# How do I replace a bathtub drain trip lever?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, hardware, drains

The trip lever for the drain in my bath tub is very old (I'm guessing 30+ years) and has begun corroding and rusting. It's definitely time to replace it. I plan to replace the entire trip lever along with the trim plate, linkage, and drain plug.

Any tips for replacing it with a new one? What should I look for when buying the replacement parts? Are they all standard or do I need to be sure to look for a particular size to fit the existing tub? Any gotchas I should be aware of while removing the old one or installing the new one?

Comment: What I'm worried about is whether I'll have to take out the tub or part of the wall to work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admittedly, I haven't done it before but I came across instructions awhile ago (courtesy of eHow and Google).  Maybe they'll be helpful.

http://www.videojug.com/film/how-to-fix-a-broken-tub-trip-lever

http://www.ehow.com/how_3391064_replace-triplever-bathtub-drain.html

-M

Comment: I ended up just taking the old one out and taking it to the store with me. The "eHow" walk-through pretty much covers it. The parts are pretty much standard, so finding a replacement was easy. Installing was also easy. In the end it was all pretty simple, really.

Answer (score 2):

better to remove the old one, then bring it with you when you do shopping, then show to the place where is you gonna buy it, or go to the second hand renovation shop and could be they have a spare of the old bathtub. But I believe there is have somewhere. And I think they are still standard...
Good luck : )

Answer (score 0):

Mike B.'s answer is correct. But also, you might not need to replace it.

After watching the first video in Mike B's answer, I took mine apart. The video showed a spiral spring. My spring was actually a bent piece of sheet metal (kind of like a U with a dimple in one side). It had simply become loose and needed to be put back in place.